# UIButton is not working after adding Subview on present view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, addsubview

I have a ViewController1(`notificationVC`) with some button and I want to insert view of this VC1 to another VC2(`infoView`).

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NotificationVC *notificationVC = [[NotificationVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"NotificationVC" bundle:nil];
    notificationVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, _infoView.frame.size.height-425,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 400);
    [_infoView addSubview:notificationVC.view];
}
```

This code works fine for displaying View, but issue is, after displaying it UIButton does't work.

Comment: UIButton's IBAction is in NotificationVC so it will not be called from infoView. You can use NSNotification to achieve this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because notification VC should handle gestures in that ViewController. to achieve these add ViewController as child

```
[_infoView addSubview:notificationVC.view];
[self addChildViewController: notificationVC];
```

Don't forget to remove it